# Measuring memory usage of scikit-learn changes model performance

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory, scikit-learn, memory-profiling

I am trying to measure memory usage of my models in scikit-learn using [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) python module. However, when I profile memory during training, the model shows different accuracy as when I train it without profiling. (With profiling, the performance is much worse)
The code how I measure it:

```
clf = svm.SVC()
mem = memory_usage((clf.fit, (X_train, y_train)), max_usage=True)

pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(pred, y_test))
```

Does anyone have experience with this? What could be the cause?

Comment: out of curiosity - how big is the data in this example ?

Comment: if you fit your classifier multiple times, will the accuracy remain constant?

Comment: @user702846 It is around 50MB of text data, transformed by TFIDF.

Comment: @FarhoodET When I fitted the model for the second time (without profiling), the accuracy dropped to 0.

Comment: I don't think memory_usage is made to estimate memory usage as such ! per documention, it is made for data frames. what you are returning is a classier  - so I guess, there is no fit and it is just a random initiation of svc that leads to such a low performance.

Comment: @Pastrami so I think the problem is with the data and how you fit it. If you create a new model and fit it again instead of fitting a model twice, how will the accuracy change?

Comment: please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with a statistical analysis, then you could give [Austin](https://github.com/P403n1x87/austin) a try. It is a statistical profiler that can also profile memory usage. A really good feature is that you don't need to instrument your code. You could just run your application in production and attach Austin to it with extremely minimal performance impacts.

Austin is available for easy installation from many package providers, like Homebrew, Chocolatey, Snap Store and the Debian official repository. There are also binary releases available from GitHub.

Have a look at the README to see how to use it. In general, things are as easy as just

```sh
austin -m yourpythonapp
```

If you want to attach to a running process, get its PID and do

```sh
sudo austin -mp <pid>
```